# Domain of convergence of complex series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I have the complex series: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ (n/n+1)(z/2)^n$
Using Cauchy I get radius of convergence $R=2$.
I know that the series  is convergent for |z|<2 , does it converge for |z|=2 ?

Comment: It seems the radius should be bigger than one.  I'm pretty sure it converges for $z=2$, no?

Comment: Oops , now I have edited my question

Comment: It may help to write out the cauchy criterion.  I believe the radius is $2$... and it looks like the series should be centered at $z=0$?  (Assuming no more edits to the question.)

Comment: It's (z/2)^n not z^n so R=2 not 1

Comment: @MalakDiab Did you mean $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{n+1} \left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's clear that the radius is 2. If you want to know the domain of convergence you must study the convergence in the circunference |z|=2, i.e. $z=2e^{it}$. In this case you need to look to series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{n+1}e^{int}$ with $t\in[0,2\pi]$. Next step is to split in real and imaginary parts, then using Abel-Dirichlet convergence criterion study the convergence of the series. This is the general "algorithm".

In this particular case the work is easier, beacuse the general term doesn't satisfy the necessary condition for convergence: $\displaystyle\lim_{n}\left|\frac{n}{n+1}e^{int}\right|=\lim_n\frac{n}{n+1}=1$. So, the domain of convergence is the open disc $|z|<2$.

Know the work is all done!:)

Comment: Why not in |z|=2.

Comment: Can show me more details please