# Convergence of a complex power series

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the series: 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n!}{n^n}z^n$$

I found radius of convergence using almbert $R=e$

I know that this series converges for $|z|<e$ , does it converge for |z|=e

Comment: I'm sure somebody posted this exact same question earlier today, I think the answer was $R=2$.

Comment: I think this case is harder

Comment: "almbert=Lambert?"

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Or maybe even d'Alembert.

Comment: D'alembert ....

Comment: @GregoryGrant, this is exactly why I'm not answering this particular question.  The back and forth...

Comment: Why doesn't the solution you received here work in the same manner: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1309484/domain-of-convergence-of-complex-series/1309501#1309501

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Letting $z = ee^{i\theta}$, your sum becomes

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{e}{n}\right)^nn!\,e^{in\theta}.$$

In order for the sum to converge, we need that the summand goes to zero as $n$ tends to infinity. Does that happen here?

Comment: I'm asking if that happens here

Comment: I have given you a *very* good hint. Any more and I'll be giving you the answer.

Comment: I reached here , so if I know how to continue I won't ask any more

Comment: @CameronWilliams, this is exactly what happened when he asked a similar question earlier today: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1309484/domain-of-convergence-of-complex-series/1309501#1309501... just a heads up...

Comment: @TravisJ I just saw that in your comment above. I'll leave him to figure it out from here. Thanks for the heads-up! Much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Let's use Stirling's formula: $n! \sim \sqrt{2\pi n} (n/e)^n$, so you have $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n!}{n^n} e^n e^{int} \sim \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt{2\pi n}  e^{int}$$ if $|z|=e$. But $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}|\sqrt{2\pi n}  e^{int}| = \infty$, and hence еhis series diverges.

Comment: Don't use $=$ unless you actually mean $=$